# How to Connect Two Inputs in a Neural Network

Tags: algorithm, deep-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am new in deep learning and I am trying to build a model for forex trading (for research and academic purposes) which involves the analysis of economic data news (economic data release, e.g. inflation rate) and the usual pattern analysis of currency prices.

My idea is to analyze economic data (expected against actual) and see how the learning mechanism reacts thus creating a buy or sell recommendation. However, on this, I would like to consider also the historical price movements to have a great understanding of both fundamental and technical analysis.

I have tried with two neural networks: a RNN for economic data and a LSTM for the historical prices, but I don't know how to link those two to create the output. In summary, my attempt was:

- Two inputs: economic data news (numerical data), currency price
  (numerical data)
- Two networks (RNN and LSTM)
- Output: +1 (buy) -1(sell)

However, I don't think is the best strategy or I don't know how to link two networks to create the signal. How to do that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: PS: I am using python - Keras

Comment: Make a third neural network, that takes as input the output of the two networks, and outputs +1 or -1.